# Importing data from MS Access?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ms-access

I'm trying to import data from MS Access but unsuccessful. The commands tab (Customize> customize mode> commands) doesn't show "ArcCatalog", so I'm stuck here being failed to add "Add OLE DB Connection" which is required to import MS Access data file into ArcGIS. I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.1.

Can anyone tell what to do now to import MS Access data into ArcGIS?

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=how+to+import+mdb+to+arcgis

Comment: Can you click on the `Windows` tab at the top and select `Catalog`?

Answer (score 2):

Go to:

```
Customize > Customize Mode > Commands
```

Put "Catalog" in the Show Commands Containing, and after will be display

```
File > Catalog
Tools > ArcCatalog
```

After activate the Catalog, just click with the right button in any folder and go to:

```
New > ...
```

I suggest to verify your ODBC Drivers:

http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000009382

And after please read this documentation:

http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/connecting-to-a-microsoft-access-database.htm

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It's very helpful. Now, I'm successful to import MS Access data to ArcGIS 10.3.1.